# Line integral of$ \int_c \frac{dz}{(1 - z )^3}$ , where $ C$ is circle $|z| = \frac{1}{2}$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

(a) Iintegral of$ \int_c \frac{dz}{(1 - z )^3}$ , where $ C$  is circle $|z| = \frac{1}{2}$

I try with

put $u =1-z $ then $du =-dz$

$\int (-du/u^3)= 1/2u^2$

is that correct ??

(b) Integral of$\int_c\frac{e^z}{(1 - z )^3 } dz $, $C$ is circle $|z - 1| = 1/2$

this not understand it

Answer (score 0):

(a) $f$ is analytic in $|z|=\frac{1}{2}$. So the integral is $0$ ( by Cauchy's theorem) .

(b) $f$ has a pole of order $3$ at $z=1$. So by Cauchy's theorem , given integral $=\frac{2\pi i}{2!}g''(1)$ , where , $g(z)=e^z$.